# how to set overflow: hidden; to one element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a div that slides across the page. I am just playing around with keyframes in CSS trying to learn what all it can do.

I want this div to act as a curtain, so when it slides, everything behind it will change. NOw, when the div goes beyond the scope of what the user can see, the browser allows the user to scroll to see everything.. How do I stop the user from being able to see the over flow of that ONE element? Here's a fiddle.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvtr6/)

Code:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="hide"><div class="curtain"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    }
    .hide {overflow: hidden;}
    .curtain {
        -webkit-animation:curtainMove 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        margin-left: -2100px;
        margin-top: -300px;
        background-color: black;
        height: 2000px;
        width: 4000px;
        transform:rotate(50deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(50deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(140deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        z-index: 13;
        float: left;
        position:absolute;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes curtainMove /* Safari and Chrome */{
    from {
        margin-left: -2500px;
        margin-top: -2500px;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 600px;
        margin-top: 600px;
    }
}
    .content {
    background-color: #9F3;
    height: 1200px;
    width: 740px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 12;
    }
```

Comment: `.curtain {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: This does not work... @Morpheus

Comment: give width and height to `.curtain` div of `100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvtr6/3/

```
<div class="hide">
    <div class="curtain"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

.hide {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

And then remove `position: absolute;` on `.content` to fill the parent. Given the necessary solution, you might consider renaming your div class `.hide` to something like `.outer`.

Comment: Aha! I see what you did. Thank you for this. @StuartKershaw